# Python Вычислить разность i-тих элементов списка?

Tags: python

Как вычислить разницу всех элементов списка.

```
lis[1,2,5,8,9,2, ..., n] # (1 - 2 - 5 - 8 - 9 - 2 - ....) // -25
```

Answer (score 3):

Почитайте о срезах

```
 l[0]-sum(l[1:])
```

(хотя разностью i-x элементов это трудно назвать)

Answer (score 1):

Взять 1й элемент списка и вычесть из него суму остальных